# How to Calculate the Difference Between Two Rows in SQL [PostgreSQL] - For Aggregated Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, lag

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE fake_sales
(
    group_id INT NOT NULL,
    year SMALLINT CHECK(year > 0),
    amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(year, group_id)
);
```

I want to compare the current year's sale with the last year's sale using `LAG` window function.

Like this:

```
SELECT
    year,
    SUM(amount) AS annual_sale,
    LAG(annual_sale, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY year) change_amount
FROM fake_sales
GROUP BY year;
```

but I can't get the desired result and I got this error

> ERROR: column "annual_sale" does not exist

How to compare a record (row) to previous record for an aggregated column?

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate aggregated `SUM` column first, then use `LAG` to calculate the difference.

```
SELECT 
    year,
    annual_sale,
    (annual_sale - LAG(annual_sale) OVER (ORDER BY year)) AS change_amount
FROM  
    (SELECT
        year,
        SUM(amount) AS annual_sale
    FROM fake_sales
    GROUP BY year) data;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5BBmR8rh).

Comment: I'm afraid your lag function will always return null

Answer (score 0):

It's because column `annual_sale` really doesn't exist: alias is not allowed in lead. You should use `SUM(amount)` (or use sub-query).

Also you don't need to partition your lag.

```sql
SELECT
    year,
    SUM(amount) AS annual_sale,
    LAG(SUM(amount)) OVER (
        ORDER BY year
    ) - SUM(amount) change_amount
FROM fake_sales
GROUP BY year;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8s3bsvDk)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest aggregating by year first, then taking the lag in sales.

```sql
SELECT
    year,
    SUM(amount) AS annual_sales,
    LAG(SUM(amount)) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS prev_year_sales
FROM fake_sales
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```